# Javascript copy to clipboard including html formatted text

Tags: javascript, button, copy

I'm relatively new to js so would like some help,

I've got a form which is generated in php. I want the user to be able to click a button and copy the flight results to the clipboard,

I have the following javascript function:

```
<script>

function copyToClipboard(element) {
var $temp = $("<textarea>");
var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
$("body").append($temp);
$temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n")).select();
document.execCommand("copy");
$temp.remove();
}

</script>
```

However when you paste the result i get the following with the formatting tags visible:

```
<b>Mon 09 Oct - DY 7015 </b> 
Depart: London Gatwick Airport,  (LGW) at 17:05
Arrive: John F Kennedy Airport, New York (JFK) at 20:05
```

I want the result input to be

**Mon 09 Oct - DY 7015**  
Depart: London Gatwick Airport,  (LGW) at 17:05
Arrive: John F Kennedy Airport, New York (JFK) at 20:05

or if this is not possible easily, then at the very least display without formatting but also without the tags

Mon 09 Oct - DY 7015 
Depart: London Gatwick Airport,  (LGW) at 17:05
Arrive: John F Kennedy Airport, New York (JFK) at 20:05

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex to remove your HTML tags: `/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g`

So, this should work :

```
$(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n").replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g, '')
```

Hope this helps!